# Amplify Vue Chatbot not setting up

Tags: vue.js, aws-amplify, amazon-lex

I'm trying to use the Amplify Chatbot Component in my application but I keep getting:

> Chatbot - Bot not provided.

I've used the Amplify CLI to add Interactions, which added the correct configuration into the aws-exports.js file. I then set the Amplify.Configure to use the exports file.

But when I try to use the component in my app, I can't seem to get it to run.

### App.vue

```
<template>
  <amplify-chatbot ></amplify-chatbot>
</template>

<script>
import { Interactions } from 'aws-amplify';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Interactions
  },
  data(){
    return {
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

### AWS-Exports

```
// WARNING: DO NOT EDIT. This file is automatically generated by AWS Amplify. It will be overwritten.

const awsmobile = {
    "aws_project_region": "eu-west-1",
    "aws_cognito_identity_pool_id": "eu-west-1:fbc545c0-ddac-410b-8f8d-4ba3cffadbb2",
    "aws_cognito_region": "eu-west-1",
    "oauth": {},
    "aws_bots": "enable",
    "aws_bots_config": [
        {
            "name": "ScheduleAppointment_dev",
            "alias": "$LATEST",
            "region": "eu-west-1"
        }
    ]
};


export default awsmobile;
```

### main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import Amplify, * as AmplifyModules from 'aws-amplify'
import { AmplifyPlugin } from 'aws-amplify-vue'
import awsconfig from './aws-exports'
Amplify.configure(awsconfig)

Vue.use(AmplifyPlugin, AmplifyModules)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: I have never used aws-amplify, so this is a shot in the dark, but I don't see you using `awsmobile` anywhere (I see it defined, but not imported and used anywhere).

Comment: See https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/interactions#configure-your-app

Comment: Hey AlaxMA, thanks for commenting and even another pair of eyes helps. I have the main.js importing the aws-exports file, I'll add it above just so it's clearer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of your app.vue and that will work:

```
<template>
  <amplify-chatbot v-bind:chatbotConfig="chatbotConfig"></amplify-chatbot>
</template>

<script>
import { Interactions } from 'aws-amplify';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: () => ({
   chatbotConfig:{
     bot: "addTheBotNameHere",
     clearComplete: true
    },
  }),
  mounted() {
   Interactions.onComplete("addTheBotNameHere", this.handleComplete);
},
  methods: {

    handleComplete(err,confirmation) {

      if(err) {
         alert("bot conversation failed");
         return;
      }

      return "Thank You";
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```